# YII2 extra condition with AND operator

Tags: yii2, updates, multiple-conditions

I'm updating a record in this way:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('table', ['config' => json_encode($array)], 
        'field1 = :field1', [':field1' => $field1] 
        )->execute();
```

My aim is to add an extra condition with the `AND` operator but I don't know how to do it.

I've followed this example: [LINK](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/db-dao#non-select-queries)

```
 // UPDATE (table name, column values, condition)
 Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update('user', ['status' => 1], 'age > 30')->execute();
```

But it doesn't show a lot of possibilities.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this way

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()
             ->update('table', ['config' => json_encode($array)],
             'field1 = :field1 AND field2 = :field2',[':field1' =>  $field1,':field2' =>  $field2])
             ->execute();
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like an array, with each condition separated by a `,`.

In your case:

```
Yii::$app->db->createCommand()->update(
  'table', 
   ['config' => json_encode($array)], 
   ['field1' => $field1, 'field2' => $field2]
)->execute();
```

Note that with this syntax you don't need to bind params, you could specify them directly inside the array of conditions as Yii2 santizes them.